# Email sent after jenkins job lost?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, smtp, ssmtp

I have a jenkins job setup on UBUNTU, that is to execute some test scripts, and after each execution, the email will be automatically sent to notify the team. It used to work pretty well. But just recently, I am not getting any email any more. But in the job console output, it says:

```
...
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: ...  
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Where I may check if the email does send out ???

Comment: Which plugin are you using for sending mails?

Comment: My Jenkins version is 2.176.1. The plug-in I am using is Email-EXT Plug-in, of version 2.69.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I've read you're using the Extended Email Plugin.

You can track the issue down with the help of the debug mode of this extension. You can enable the debug mode in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System (global settings) -> Extended E-mail Notification -> Enable Debug Mode. Then [check your Jenkins log file](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/).

If the plugin can send the email, then the problem is not related to Jenkins.